# How to override public folder path in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to use a different *public* folder from a parent directory called *client* which contains the entire AngularJS app. Essentially I want to tell Rails to load AngularJS app and the only job that Rails has to do is serve JSON.

Is that possible in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: That's a pretty bad idea. Even if there is a way (I'm sure there is), I'd be worried that some  gem will have `Rails.root.join('public')` hard-coded into it. Serving static assets out of `/public` is a pretty strong Rails convention.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to override the existing `public` folder, because there are some dependency. Normally rails application runs in Webrick server, but in-case in production environment you want to run your application in Apache web server then you will face problem. Because Apache runs Rails application with Passenger module. And Apache only accept/consider the `public` folder as your web root. Hope you got my idea.

Comment: @meagar The standard way of getting public folder location is `Rails.public_path` which returns `application.paths["public"].first`. If a gem is hardcoding paths and ignoring rails configuration - the gem shouldn't be worth your attention ;)

Answer (score 9):

As others have mentioned, it may or may not be a great idea to override the existing `paths['public']` folder. But you can do the following safely in somewhere like `application.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_after(
  ActionDispatch::Static,
  ActionDispatch::Static,
  Rails.root.join("client").to_s,
  Rails.application.config.static_cache_control
)
```

The `public` folder [is exposed to the web server through the Rack middleware `ActionDispatch::Static`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb#L21). There's nothing else special about it, and the above code simply adds another instance of the middleware that points to the directory `client`. So in the above case, the browser would be able to access everything in `public` as well as `client`.

Comment: Works beautifully!

Comment: for Rails5.2 replace `config.static_cache_control` by `index: config.public_file_server.index_name, headers: config.public_file_server.headers || {}`

Answer (score 1):

Just had to do it myself for an Angular app.

Put this in your application.rb:

```
config.serve_static_files = true
paths['public'] = File.join 'client', 'app'
```

Or if you still use asset pipeline (`config.assets.enabled = true`):

```
paths['public/javascripts'] = File.join 'client', 'app', 'scripts'
paths['public/stylesheets'] = File.join 'client', 'app', 'styles'
```

Would be interesting to know if there are any consequences with the second bit as my front-end is served completely separately thus I keep asset pipeline switched off and use grunt instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can define another path like

```
# config/application.rb
paths['my_website'] = 'website'
```

Then you can use this path in your routes like

```
# routes.rb
get '/my_website', to: redirect('my_website/index.html')
```