# Add additional front-end folder to serve static html pages in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to display some static landing pages on my Rails application. As of now I'm putting all the static `.html` pages inside the `my_app/public/website` folder and mapping routes like

```
match '', :to => redirect('/website/index.html')
```

There is a link on that static page and on clicking on that link user will be redirected to my main rails application.

Now I need to move folder inside of `public` ie, `website/*` to root directory like `my_app/website/`.

I've changed folder structure as above and change routes as

```
match '', :to => redirect('website/index.html')
```

and I'm getting this error

```
ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme http does not accept registry part
```

This was just the hit and trial approach and to be honest with you I'm not sure if it is possible to do so. I am guessing if there is any configuration options that is present that would allow me to make any root level directory to server static assets.

Many thanks

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have a webserver like nginx serving your rails app you can configure nginx to server all the static content and also make some redirects. Is it important that your Rails app handles redirects and content delivery?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the folder that is to be used as public in `config/application.rb` file as follows.

```
paths['public'] = 'website'
```

And then you can define your routes as

```
get '', :to => redirect('index.html')
```

Alternatively, you can put the whole thing inside the `frontend` folder, this way there will be less chance of any name conflict if you have multiple static pages

```
# config/application.rb
paths['public'] = 'frontend'
```

and

```
# config/routes.rb
get '', :to => redirect('website/index.html')
```

Hope it helps.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31610032/3587928)

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the existing public folder is not a good idea. You should define another path like `paths['my_website'] = 'website'` in `config/application.rb`

Then you can use this path in your routes like

```
get '/my_website', :to => redirect('my_website/index.html')
```